# Carrierwave to different upload folder | Routes not correct

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, rvm, capistrano, carrierwave

I need to configure my carrierwave gem in rails to use a different upload folder beyond the whole rails scope.

I have a VPS and using RVM, ruby, rails. I'm deploying with capistrano, but every time a deploy takes place, the upload folder changes to the new deployed version and not taking all the older images with it.

I want to have a folder that is static and not going to be changed every deployment. But i cant seem to get the solid settings, the cache and store directories are being changed. Also when i'm using Rails.root (this gets me the current capistrano deployment folder) need to get 1 or 2 maps above this folder (way beyond the rails.root)

How could i change this settings so that this is going to work?

Thank you for your time

**Update**

Changed to full url : /home/deploy/rails_apps/site/uploads/ and its being uploaded. Only when i want to display the picture, this gives me a X mark. If i want to open the image by the firebug inspector, it gives me the error:

No route matches [GET] "/home/deploy/rails_apps/site/uploads/product/image/5/thumb_test.png"

How must i make a route that's beyond this application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using shared configs with symlinks with Capistrano on your VPS?
If so, you can make there a config for carrier wave picture folder which won't get overwritten. Than you can also use different setting on dev- and deployment machine.

You can take a look at this screencast: [Capistrano Tasks from Ryan Bates](http://railscasts.com/episodes/133-capistrano-tasks)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thats what i wanted! Thank you, didn't know about symlinks, thank!